# UIView bottom constraint after rotate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have UIProgressView that i transformed (rotated) so it would be vertical, my issue is with the bottom constraint which is not appearing correctly since the view is rotated, the bottoms of UIView and UIProgressView and not exactly aligned, i tried also to change the anchor point, couldn't the bottoms to be aligned as well.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self initFlow];
    self._wProgressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] init];
    [self._middleRightView addSubview:self._wProgressView];
    [self._wProgressView setProgress:0.7];
    CGPoint newCenter = self._wProgressView.layer.anchorPoint;
    newCenter.x = 0;
    newCenter.y = 1;
    [self._wProgressView.layer setAnchorPoint:newCenter];
    self._wProgressView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self._wProgressView.transform, -0.5 *M_PI);
//    [self._wProgressView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self._wProgressView.superview.centerXAnchor].active = YES;
    self._wProgressView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self._wProgressView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self._wImageView.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    [self._wProgressView.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self._wProgressView.superview.heightAnchor multiplier:0.5].active = YES;
    [self._wProgressView.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self._wProgressView.superview.widthAnchor constant:0.8].active = YES;
    //= self._wProgressView.superview.centerXAnchor;

}
```

Comment: You don't show any information about `_middleRightView` or `_wImageView`, so it's not entirely clear what you are trying to do...  Can you post an image of what your goal is?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work this way:

You should give only height, width and Center x and y constraint of UIProgressView to UIView relation

No Need to give bottom constraint of UIProgressView

this work for me I Hope this will help you...!

Comment: they are not the same height, so center Y and X wouldn't help

Comment: Okay you should try first remove all constraint of  UIProgressView then rotate after that give 0.1s delay and give constraint to UIProgressView and call layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: more elegant way ?

Comment: no and it will not work when the iphone is in landscape